# Examples of some complex queries for Data Warehousing

Tags: data-warehouse

This may not be the right platform to ask Database/Data warehousing questions but since there is a lot in common between the two, I will ask.

I'm only starting to study Data warehousing and I have to do a project.  I would like some suggestions/ideas on the types of complex queries that can done be with my project.

I have 2 databases.  The first database contains tables Customer, Purchase, Products and Promotions.  The second table contains Supplier, Product and Order tables.

What kind of complex queries could I perform?

Comment: 1) Purchases in the month of June for the last 5 years.  2) Purchases in each region for 2015.  3) Purchases in the first quarter of 2015 vs the last quarter of 2015.  That should be enough to get you started.

Comment: what sort of queries could I do with a promotion's table ?

Comment: 1) Promotions for the month of June for the last 5 years.  2) Promotions in each region for 2015.  3) Promotions in the first quarter of 2015 vs. the third quartyer of 2015.   That should be enough to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Database is used for transport processing while Data warehouse is used for Analytical Processing.

Data base is used for recording historical data while Data warehouse is used for business decisions.

DB is optimized for write operation and DWH is optimized for read operation.
Response time of DB is more for analytical queries while for DWH it is less